# In QGIS are there similare construction tools to ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, features, editing, tools

For a project we are using ArcGIS to reshape autogenerated features. For that we often use the construction tools polygon, rectangel, circle, etc in ArcGIS. The right angle is also an often used tool. Are there some similar construction tools in QGIS? I found the CADTool-plugin and the Freehand-plugin, but that seems not to be the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the "Rectangles ovals digitizing” [plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/rectovalDigit/) in the official QGIS repository.

To activate the tools in the tool bar you have to first select a vector layer containing polygon or multipolygon features. After that start editing on this layer.
Of course, it doesn't work for vector layers containing point or linestring features.

Comment: Ok thank you! It works a little bit different than in ArcGIS - I'll try this.